# SQL: How Do I Use LIKE Keyword on the Column Rather than Just One Value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

The following are 2 queries I tried without any success of getting the results I want:

```
SELECT H.Type, H.SN, R.Type, R.SN  
FROM Hours H 
INNER JOIN Repair R
ON H.SN = R.SN AND H.Type LIKE '%' + R.Type
```

AND

```
SELECT H.Type, H.SN, R.Type, R.SN  
FROM Hours H 
INNER JOIN Repair R
ON H.SN = R.SN AND H.Type LIKE '%R.Type'
```

How do I use the `LIKE` keyword for the column rather than one value?  I.E  I want the H.Type = 424 to be JOINED to R.Type = 424A

EDIT:

The following are some sample results I'm getting after making the recommended adjustments:

```
---------------------------------------
H.Type    |H.SN    |R.Type   |R.SN    |
---------------------------------------
R99       |270     |EMPTY    |270     |    
R99       |270     |EMPTY    |270     |     
R99       |270     |EMPTY    |270     |     
R99       |270     |EMPTY    |270     |
B134      |427     |EMPTY    |427     |
B134      |427     |EMPTY    |427     |
B134      |427     |EMPTY    |427     |
B134      |427     |EMPTY    |427     |
```

There should be no empty fields.  Why are there?

Comment: You want multiple partial matches: `'%' + R.Type + '%'` This will match `H.Type` to any string containing `R.Type`

Answer (score 3):

Your first query is correct except you transposed the value needing the wildcard and then just add another percentage symbol.

```
AND R.Type LIKE '%' + H.Type + '%'
```

The `%` is the wildcard so as you had it it would match `A424` but not `424A`.

With percent symbols on both sides it will match `A424A` as well as `424A`

There is a performance hit for each percent symbol, so if your requirements are as specific as you say you'd only need the percent on the right side of `H.Type`.

Comment: I agree with this...but why am I still getting empty fields for `R.Type`?

Answer (score 2):

You are doing the comparison backwards.  You want:

```
and R.Type like H.Type + '%'
```

This will match:

- R.type = `424A`
- H.type = `424`

If `H.Type` is number, then cast it first:

```
and R.Type like cast(H.type as varchar(255)) + '%'
```

Comment: Made the adjustment, however I am still receiving empty fields for R.Type.  Why is this.  It shouldn't be empty right?

Comment: If `H.Type` is empty, then they will match.

Comment: I have query results with H.Type NOT empty and R.Type empty.

Comment: @JeffOrris . . . With the above logic, an empty `R.Type` should not match an `H.Type` that has a value.

Comment: @JeffOrris . . . Try editing your question with examples of matches that you are finding.

Comment: I added the results I'm getting to my question.

Comment: Are you *sure* the condition is:  `R.Type like H.Type + '%'`, with `R.Type` on the left and `H.TYpe` on the right?

Comment: Its `H.Type LIKE  '%' + R.Type` `H.Type` is on the left

Comment: @JeffOrris . . . That is the wrong expression.  Use the correct one.